# Confused about custom data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

**The task:** I am trying to create a custom data type and have it able to print to the console. I also want to be able to sort it using Haskell's natural ordering.

**The issue:** Write now, I can't get this code to compile. It throws the following error: `No instance for (Show Person) arising from a use of 'print'`.

**What I have so far:**

```
-- Omitted working selection-sort function

selection_sort_ord :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
selection_sort_ord xs = selection_sort (<) xs

data Person = Person { 
    first_name :: String, 
    last_name :: String,   
    age :: Int }            

main :: IO ()
main = print $ print_person (Person "Paul" "Bouchon" 21)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a `Show` instance to convert the type to a printable representation (a `String`). The easiest way to obtain one is to add

```
deriving Show
```

to the type definition.

```
data Person = Person { 
    first_name :: String, 
    last_name :: String,   
    age :: Int }
      deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

to get the most often needed instances.

If you want a different `Ord` instance, as suggested in the comments, instead of deriving that (keep deriving `Eq` and `Show` unless you want different behaviour for those), provide an instance like

```
instance Ord Person where
    compare p1 p2 = case compare (age p1) (age p2) of
                      EQ -> case compare (last_name p1) (last_name p2) of
                              EQ -> compare (first_name p1) (first_name p2)
                              other -> other
                      unequal -> unequal
```

or use pattern matching in the definition of `compare` if you prefer,

```
    compare (Person first1 last1 age1) (Person first2 last2 age2) =
        case compare age1 age2 of
          EQ -> case compare last1 last2 of
                  EQ -> compare first1 first2
                  other -> other
          unequal -> unequal
```

That compares according to age first, then last name, and finally, if needed, first name.

Comment: Cool, thank you. So the Eq and Ord will allow Person to be sorted naturally?

Comment: Yup, with an `Ord` instance (which requires `Eq`), the standard `sort` from `Data.List` is available for sorting.

Comment: And if I wanted to use `selection_sort_ord` (above) to sort a list of Person’ items in order of increasing age, using the `instance` keyword to write my own `compare` function, any suggestions on how I'd do this?

Comment: Is the question about how to write the `compare` function? It depends on how you want `Person`s to compare; if you want it to be by last name then first name, ignoring age, for instance, you could (after importing `Control.Arrow` and `Data.Function`) do `instance Ord Person where compare = compare \`on\` (last_name &&& first_name)`

Comment: `selection_sort_ord` doesn't allow any customisation, it takes a list and does with it, well, whatever `selection_sort` does when passed the comparison `(<)` and a list. To sort according to age, I would recommend to use the handy `comparing` function from `Data.Ord`, then it would just be `sortBy (comparing age)` - (`sortBy` is from `Data.List`). If you want the `Ord` instance to consider `age` first, I'll put an example in my answer, give me a few minutes to type it up.

Comment: Thank you both very, very much.

Comment: Why has nobody mentioned `mappend`?  You can write it as: `let (<+>) = mappend in compare age1 age2 <+> compare last1 last2 <+> compare first1 first2`